# How to find out if the thread/task started by Executor.execute() ( not ExecutorService ) completed?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, Executor class does not have shutdown/shutdownNow()/awaitTermination like ExecutorService subclass. So if you start a task/thread by invoking executorObject.execute(runnableTask), how can you check if that task completed ?

Comment: If you have control over the Runnable’s code, you can put something at the end of its `run` method.  Otherwise, unless the Executor happens to be an ExecutorService, there is no way to know when a task has been run.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with `Executor` simply because it provides a single method `void execute(Runnable)`. Unless you consider using `Executor` implementations that return `Future`, you can implement notify/wait mechanism of your own:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
Runnable task = () -> {
   try {
      // ... do useful work
   } finally {
      latch.countDown();
   }
}

executorObject.execute(task);

// wrap into try/catch for InterruptedException
// if not propagating further
latch.await(); // await(timeout);
```